# How can I enable encrypted HTTPS for Nginx web server using Let's Encrypt?

Tags: webserver, letsencrypt

As the question asks, for Ubuntu 18.04 how can I effectively enable encrypted HTTPS on the Nginx web server? Specifically, i need to use Let's Encrypt to install free TLS/SSL certificates to enable encryption.

Comment: I think the documentation is pretty good. Can you explain more in detail what is your specific problem with https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started or  https://certbot.eff.org ?

Comment: Ah I see there is no 18.04 in the dropdown ... But it's in the ppa, you can just use the [17.10 description](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntuartful-nginx).

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick.

Install the Certbot software on your server.
Add the repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
```

Update the package list to pick up the new repository's package information:

```
sudo apt update
```

Install Certbot's Nginx package with apt:

```
sudo apt install python-certbot-nginx
```

Allow HTTPS traffic by allowing the Nginx Full profile and delete the redundant Nginx HTTP profile allowance:

```
sudo ufw allow 'Nginx Full'
sudo ufw delete allow 'Nginx HTTP'
```

Obtain an SSL Certificate using Nginx plugin:

```
sudo certbot --nginx -d example.com -d www.example.com
```

Let me know if I forgot anything and I will edit accordingly.

Comment: Ah, yes. Nginx Full, of course! :)